# document.save("output.pdf") RuntimeError: Proxy error(ArgumentNullException): Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'key') Python Aspose-PDF PDT to EXECL

Tags: python, tableau-api, aspose

I am trying to convert pdf to Excel using aspose pdf it works okay on a local machine without downloading the file from Tableau but when I download the file and the downloading is good to go when I pass the directory path it loads and converts it but on save it shows error.

```
def convert_pdfs_to_excel(directory):
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(directory):
        for file in files:
            file_path = os.path.join(root, file)
            if file_path.endswith(".pdf"):
                output_xlsx = file_path[:-4] + ".xlsx"

                document = ap.Document(file_path)
                save_options = ap.ExcelSaveOptions()
                save_options.format = ap.ExcelSaveOptions.ExcelFormat.XLSX
                document.save(output_xlsx, save_options)

                # Remove the first row from the Excel file
                workbook = openpyxl.load_workbook(output_xlsx)
                sheet = workbook.active
                # sheet.delete_rows(1)

                # Save the modified Excel file
                workbook.save(output_xlsx)
                print("Aspose title removed from Excel successfully!")

                # Convert Excel to CSV using pandas
                df = pd.read_excel(output_xlsx, header=None)
                df = df.iloc[1:, :]

                # Save the DataFrame to Excel without the first row
                df.to_excel(output_xlsx, index=False, header=False)
                print("First row removed from CSV successfully!")
```

Comment: It looks like a similar topic is already under discussion in official support forum of Aspose.PDF (https://forum.aspose.com/t/runtimeerror-proxy-error-argumentnullexception-value-cannot-be-null-parameter-key/262653/20). We request you please follow up there so that you can be assisted further accordingly. Please note that official support forums are the right and recommended place to discuss such matters. This is Asad Ali and I am Developer Evangelist at Aspose.